# How can I use data filtering(?) on my app?

Tags: firebase

I'm studying Java since 8/2020 ans  I'm making recipe app for my school project.
I'm using android studio,Java and currently finished making Frontend UI , every layout of my app and connected to FireBase.
on my app I want users to add their food,health data on app and get recipe which fit for their data.

At this point I want to know what tool,program should I use to build my recipe recommendation algorithm and apply it on my app,Firebase.
I searched many Question,post on google and couldn't find  what to use.

This is my  first complicated app and  I don't  know much about programming
I'm stuck at this point for 5 days. Can  somebody Help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you want any hope of having your question answered, you need to ask a *specific programming question*. It looks like you would be best served by following a tutorial somewhere else on the web.

Answer (score 1):

The question can have a vast number of answers, and it depends upon your database structure and you to decide, which approach to pick.

You need to search for the data on two bases, i.e. **ingredients and health data**

**One approach could be:**
For the ingredients part, this would do the job:

> Including an array of **tags** in each document of a recipe which would list out the ingredients of the recipe by which you can query (*array-contains*)

And for the health data part, I'm not quite sure what you mean by filtering based on health but *let's say; you are going to search for the recipes based on the **calories*** the user needs in a day. So after calculating the calories required in a day, it would be like:

> Including a field of **totalCalories** in each document of a recipe which would tell the total calories in the recipe by which you can query (*whereEqualTo* or *whereLessThan*)

I suggest you read the Firebase documentation for executing the queries to get to know about all the possible ways.
[Perform simple and compound queries in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

Comment: thank you! My original plan was show user 3 meals everyday that sum of 3 meals calories satisfy  calories users need a day. How can I make that method ?  Can i make that on firebase or get recipe from firebase first and make on my app?

Comment: You can divide the total calories needed by the user in 3 parts. Then everytime the user launches your app, you can request firebase with the desired calories. For eg. if a user needs 1500 calories in a day and you divide the 3 meals in 500 calories each. Then, just get the recipe from firebase whose **totalCalories** is equal to 500 and do the same with the other two meals.

Comment: If it helped, kindly mark it as correct answer.